# DynamoDBMapper unconvert attribute error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am getting json from dynamoDb that looks like this -

```
{
    "id": "1234",
    "payment": {
        "payment_id": "2345",
        "user_defined": {
            "some_id": "3456"
            }
        }
}
```

My aim is to get the `user_defined` field in a Java `HashMap<String, Object>` as `user_defined` field can contain any user defined fields, which would be unknown until the data arrives. Everything works fine except my `DynamoDBMapper` cannot convert the `user_defined` field to a Java `HashMap`. It is throwing this error -

```
Exception occured Response[payment]; could not unconvert attribute
```

This is how the classes looks like -

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "PaymentDetails")
public class Response {

    private String id;

    public Response() {
    }

    private Payment payment = new Payment();

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="id")
    public String getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }

    public Payment getPayment() {
        return payment;
    }

    public void setPayment(Payment payment) {
        this.payment = payment;
    }

}
```

The payment field mapper -

```
@DynamoDBDocument
public class Payment {
private String payment_id:
private HashMap<String, Object> user_defined;

public Payment() {}

public getPayment_id() {
    return payment_id;
}

public setPayment_id(String payment_id) {
    this.payment_id = payment_id;
}

@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = HashMapMarshaller.class)
    public HashMap<String, Object> getUser_defined() {
        return user_defined;
    }

    public void setUser_defined(HashMap<String, Object> user_defined) {
        this.user_defined = user_defined;
    }
}
```

The `HashMapMarshaller`(Just to check if Hashmap marshaller wasn't working with `gson`, I just defined a `Hashmap`, put in a value and return it, but seems to still not working) -

```
public class HashMapMarshaller implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, HashMap<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    public String convert(HashMap<String, Object> hashMap) {
        return new Gson().toJson(hashMap);
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, Object> unconvert(String jsonString) {
        System.out.println("jsonString received for unconverting is " + jsonString);
        System.out.println("Unconverting attribute");
        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("key", "value");

        return hashMap;

        //return new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>(){}.getType());
    }
}
```

Marshaller approach is till now not working for me. It is also not printing any of the `println`s I've put in there. I've also tried using `@DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.DynamoDBAttributeType.M)` and using `Map` instead of `HashMap` above my `user_defined` getter to no avail.

I want to find out how to convert the `user_defined` field to Java `HashMap` or `Map`. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I ran into the same situation you did.  How did you solve the problem?  Can you post an update since there appears to be no answer thus far?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make `Map<String, Object>` to `Map<String, String>`. It should work without any custom converters. Otherwise be specific about Map's value type. For example, `Map<String, SimplePojo>` should work. Don't forget to annotate `SimplePojo` class with `@DynamoDBDocument`.

With Object as a type of Map's value, DynamoDB will not able to decide which object it has to create while reading entry from DynamoDB. It should know about specific type like `String`, `Integer`, `SimplePojo` etc.

Comment: By changing the format of the comment is not displaying generic types of Map that I've mentioned in my original answer. Those are actually needed otherwise the answer is bit confusing. I'm reverting to previous format to show generic types as well.